# Win32: Prevent folder modification?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to make sure no other process changes the contents of a particular folder.  I'd like to stop other processes from creating, deleting, or modifying files within a folder.  Further, I'd like this restriction to nest down into subfolders.

I can get close to what I want by enumerating the contents of the folder and calling **CreateFile** on each file.  This has problems in that it doesn't stop new files from being created and requires I acquire *lots* of handles.

Is there an easier way to get what I want?

---

**Update**: Addressing some comments, what I want to do is to prevent modification *while* my program is running.  It's OK if the file get modified between runs.

In terms of ACLS, the app has read access to all files within the folder.

Comment: This cannot work. Directory access is controlled by user account privileges, nothing else.

Comment: I'd make it invisible and set account privileges on it.  There is probably a way to do it though like windows gives a warning about stuffing around with the windows folder.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? What if your program dies (or is forcibly terminated) while the lock is in place?

Comment: Locking files to a single access only works while your app is running, maybe that is enough?

Comment: Using ACLs assigning your app to run as a certain user and only that user has access to the file system will probably give better control

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  It may be a better idea to monitor for changes and deal with the possibility of new files added.

Answer (score 3):

ACLs would be the best way to go but if you can't get that to work for whatever reason (you're fairly thin on the details) then use a file system filter driver. Note that this isn't very straightforward. Not rocket science either, but you have to be extra careful with driver development.

http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/filterdrv/default.mspx